# Change/Edit onSelect event of an active jQuery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

If another code displays datepicker like this:

```
$('#my-datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
    // console.log()
}
});
```

and I was wondering  to add another event when the `datepicker` is selected, how will I do this?

UPDATE:
I can get the instance of the `datepicker` like this:

```
var id = document.getElementById('my-datepicker'); 
var inst = window.$.datepicker._getInst(id);
```

Comment: You can't add another event, only overwrite the existing one. To do that, see the docs http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option

Answer (score 2):

You can ovveride simply the call by using the option on the onSelect function property :

```
$( "#my-datepicker" ).datepicker("option", "onSelect", function() {
    // do some stuff 
    console.log(" another event");
});
```

See below snippet :

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#my-datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      console.log(" default event");
    }
  });
  
  $( "#my-datepicker" ).datepicker("option", "onSelect", function() {
    console.log(" another event");
});

});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='my-datepicker'>
```